# Exit from State Monad Loop

Tags: haskell

I am playing around with the State monad and queues. At the moment I have the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns, FlexibleContexts #-}
module Main where

import Criterion.Main
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Data.Sequence ((<|), ViewR ((:>)))
import qualified Data.Sequence as S

--------------------------------------------------------
data Queue a = Queue { enqueue :: [a], dequeue :: [a] }
                                        deriving (Eq, Show)
-- adds an item
push :: a -> Queue a -> Queue a
push a q = Queue (a:enqueue q) (dequeue q)

pop :: Queue a -> Maybe (a, Queue a)
pop q = if null (dequeue q) then
          go $ Queue [] (reverse (enqueue q))
        else
          go q
  where go (Queue _ []) = Nothing
        go (Queue en (x:de)) = Just (x, Queue en de)

queueTst :: Int -> Queue Int -> Queue Int
queueTst 0 q = q
queueTst n q | even n =  queueTst (n - 1) (push (100 + n) q)
             | otherwise = queueTst (n - 1)
                           (if popped == Nothing then q
                            else snd (fromJust popped))
    where popped = pop q
-------------------------------------------------------------
pushS :: a -> S.Seq a -> S.Seq a
pushS a s = a <| s

pushS' :: a -> State (S.Seq a) (Maybe a)
pushS' a = do
  s <- get
  put (a <| s)
  return Nothing

pushS'' :: a -> State (S.Seq a) (Maybe a)
pushS'' a = get >>= (\g -> put (a <| g)) >> return Nothing

popS :: S.Seq a -> Maybe (a, S.Seq a)
popS (S.viewr -> S.EmptyR) = Nothing
popS (S.viewr -> s:>r) = Just (r,s)

popS' :: State (S.Seq a) (Maybe a)
popS' = do
  se <- get
  let sl = popS'' se
  put $ snd sl
  return $ fst sl
  where popS'' (S.viewr -> S.EmptyR) = (Nothing, S.empty)
        popS'' (S.viewr -> beg:>r) = (Just r, beg)

queueTstS :: Int -> S.Seq Int -> S.Seq Int
queueTstS 0 s = s
queueTstS n s | even n = queueTstS (n - 1) (pushS (100 + n) s)
              | otherwise = queueTstS (n - 1)
                            (if popped == Nothing then s
                             else snd (fromJust popped))
      where popped = popS s

queueTstST :: Int -> State (S.Seq Int) (Maybe Int)
queueTstST n =
  if (n > 0) then
     if even n then
       pushS' (100 + n) >> queueTstST (n - 1)
     else
       popS' >> queueTstST (n - 1)
  else return Nothing

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain
  [ bench "Twin Queue" $ whnf (queueTst 550) (Queue [500,499..1] [])
  , bench "Sequence Queue" $ whnf (queueTstS 550) (S.fromList [500,499..1])
  , bench "State Queue" $ whnf
                  (runState (queueTstST 550)) (S.fromList [500,499..1])
  ]
```

That's a bit of code but really the only functions that are relevant here are `main` and `queueTstST`. is there a way to exit `queueTstST` while retaining the last "Maybe value" rather than with "Nothing"?

Answer (score 0):

```
queueTstST :: Int -> State (S.Seq Int) (Maybe Int)
queueTstST n =
  if (n > 1) then
     if even n then
       pushS' (100 + n) >> queueTstST (n - 1)
     else
       popS' >> queueTstST (n - 1)
  else popS'
```

Comment: That's not really the correct answer. Because if the 2nd last loop was a pushS' then the correct answer would be `Nothing`. If it was popS' then it would be the `Just` value of that particular popS' - not a subsequent popS'.

Comment: Yes - your right. However I was wondering if there was a way to exit the loop with the value  from the last loop ie. if you didn't know weather the 2nd last loop was odds or even.

Comment: But originally, the 2nd last loop is always a popS' because n=1, and here I'm returning the value from the n=1 loop by aborting the recursion in it.

Comment: Yes - you are correct. Interesting how much quicker the State solution is to the others. It is 45 times as quick as the "sequence Queue" or 2.11 orders of magnitude. The "Sequence Queue" is quicker than the "Twin Queue", but not by much.

Answer (score 0):

You can remember the last value if you add an argument to your recursive function.

```
queueTstST :: Int -> State (S.Seq Int) (Maybe Int)
queueTstST n = go n Nothing
  where
  go :: Int -> Maybe Int -> State (S.Seq Int) (Maybe Int)
  go n v = 
    if (n > 1)
    then if even n 
      then pushS' (100 + n) >> go (n - 1) Nothing
      else popS' >>= go (n - 1)
    else return v
```